# Swig throwing error when trying to parse c++ file

Tags: python-3.x, c++11, swig

I am not sure about the cause of this error. I tried googling but couldn't find much.

```
 typedef std::int32_t CellType;
 typedef std::array<std::int32_t, N> IndexType;
 static constexpr auto kDims = std::tuple_size< IndexType >::value;
```

The error is in 3rd line in the code above: Error: Syntax error in input(3).

P.S. this file is part of an external library. So, rewriting the module is not possible for me. Similar errors are showing at multiple locations in the file.

Edit: If I comment this line, the swig -c++ ... works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this issue. There seems to be some problem with the usage of auto type in the statement: https://github.com/swig/swig/issues/1125. I replaced auto with unsigned int and it worked!